# Determine what parameters were passed to a function

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb

Here is the disassembled code:

```
=> 0x08048d62 <+0>:     sub    $0x2c,%esp 
  0x08048d65 <+3>:     lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax 
  0x08048d69 <+7>:     mov    %eax,0xc(%esp) 
  0x08048d6d <+11>:    lea    0x18(%esp),%eax 
  0x08048d71 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp) 
  0x08048d75 <+19>:    movl   $0x804a681,0x4(%esp) 
  0x08048d7d <+27>:    mov    0x30(%esp),%eax 
  0x08048d81 <+31>:    mov    %eax,(%esp) 
  0x08048d84 <+34>:    call   0x80488d0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt> 
  0x08048d89 <+39>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax 
  0x08048d8c <+42>:    jne    0x8048d95 <phase_4+51> 
  0x08048d8e <+44>:    cmpl   $0xe,0x18(%esp) 
  0x08048d93 <+49>:    jbe    0x8048d9a <phase_4+56> 
  0x08048d95 <+51>:    call   0x8049385 <explode_bomb> 
  0x08048d9a <+56>:    movl   $0xe,0x8(%esp) 
  0x08048da2 <+64>:    movl   $0x0,0x4(%esp) 
  0x08048daa <+72>:    mov    0x18(%esp),%eax 
  0x08048dae <+76>:    mov    %eax,(%esp) 
  0x08048db1 <+79>:    call   0x8048d05 <func4> 
  0x08048db6 <+84>:    cmp    $0x25,%eax 
  0x08048db9 <+87>:    jne    0x8048dc2 <phase_4+96> 
  0x08048dbb <+89>:    cmpl   $0x25,0x1c(%esp) 
  0x08048dc0 <+94>:    je     0x8048dc7 <phase_4+101> 
  0x08048dc2 <+96>:    call   0x8049385 <explode_bomb> 
  0x08048dc7 <+101>:   add    $0x2c,%esp 
  0x08048dca <+104>:   ret
```

I know what most of the assembly instructions do, however I know through some internet searches that the parameters in func4 are (x, 0, 14)

And it appears that the parameters are stored in $esp.

How do we know where parameters are loaded based on assembly code? Is it always in $esp?

Comment: The details you're asking about are defined by the ABI of the architecture. You can find this for your architecture with research. On x86, parameters are usually pushed onto the stack, but there are various calling conventions for x86.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions
from the address, it looks like a 32bit system. for linux/x86, the arguments are on the stack and esp is the stack pointer to help you retrieve the them.